# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute

Tags: python, class, attributeerror

I'm work with python and I need a function in class like

```
class asas(object):
    def b(self):
        self.name = "Berkhan"
a = asas()
a.b().name
```

and I check this module

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Berkhan Berkdemir\Desktop\new 1.py", line 5, in <module>
    a.b().name
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

What should I do?

Comment: `name` is an attribute of the instance, so you should do `a.b()` and in a second step `print(a.name)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NoneType means that instead of an instance of whatever Class or Object you think you're working with, you've actually got None. That usually means that an assignment or function call up above failed or returned an unexpected result. See [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8949265/5352399).

So, you can do something like this.

```
class asas(object):
    def b(self):
        self.name = "Berkhan"
        return self.name

a = asas()
print(a.b()) # prints 'Berkhan'
```

or

```
class asas(object):
    def b(self):
        self.name = "Berkhan"
        return self

a = asas()
print(a.b().name) # prints 'Berkhan'
```

Answer (score 5):

`b()` returns nothing. Therefore it returns `None`.

You probably want something like this:

```
class asas(object):
    def b(self):
        self.name = "Berkhan"
        return self
a = asas()
a.b().name
```